# Entering login data using Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to input some login data using Selenium.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def LogIn():
    print("Logging in.")
    chromedriver = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~')), 'Desktop/chromedriver')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    browser.get(URL_OMITTED)
    username = selenium.find_element_by_id("txtUsario")
    password = selenium.find_element_by_id("txtClave")

    username.send_keys("USERNAME")
    password.send_keys("PASSWORD")

    selenium.find_element_by_id("btnLogin").click()

    print("Logged in.")
```

When I run this, a browser opens up with "data:," in the URL field and I get this long error that I don't understand:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 250, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 238, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"3431.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248307,platform=Mac OS X 10.11.3 x86_64)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

If I hardcode Google's address into browser.get(), I get this error

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 250, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 238, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"3522.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248307,platform=Mac OS X 10.11.3 x86_64)
```

Comment: It appears that `URL_OMITTED` doesn't contain the value you think it does. Have you verified that you're using the URL you think you are using?

Comment: The URL I am placing there is correct for sure, and so are the element IDs

Comment: <input name="txtUsuario" type="text" maxlength="30" id="txtUsuario" style="width:165px;">  ... for example of ID

Comment: Do you get the same error if you hard-code "http://www.google.com" into the call to `browser.get`?

Comment: The problem is with the `get`, it's not with the username and password.

Comment: I still get an error, and I think it's the same ... I updated OP with the error

Comment: Could it possibly be the way I wrote my path to Chromedriver (which is on my desktop) that is affecting the get function?

Comment: probably. I can't duplicate your errors on my system.

Comment: Make sure that your browser and Selenium drivers are all up to date. Any time the browser opens but doesn't navigate, that's a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using chromedriver `2.9`, the latest is `2.28`. Upgrade and you should be ok